# window.ethereum

Tags: solidity, web3js, dapps

When i made web3 instance and run index.html i lose ethereum and window.ethereum when i call it from console i got ethereum is not defined,i have installed metamask and use ropsten network.Why its happend,but when i go on site like cryptokitties it works perfect.

```
if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
 web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
} else {
 // set the provider you want from Web3.providers
 web3 = new Web3(new 
Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/148bee2b5da148a7b77a83f7504d00e7"));
}

async function asyncCall() {
  ethereum.enable()  // =========== RETURN UNDEFINED
  console.log('calling');
  const result = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
  console.log(result);
  // expected output: 'resolved'
}
asyncCall()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was running into this same issue.
Apparently nobody wants to make the solution obvious, but I finally found [this issue](https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/6562), which brought me to  [this link](https://github.com/MetaMask/faq/blob/master/DEVELOPERS.md#globe_with_meridians-https---web-server-required):

> Due to browser security restrictions, we can't communicate with dapps running on file://. Please use a local server for development.

So setting up an actual server locally fixes the issue. I just verified that this works after installing [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server).

I installed it using `npm install http-server -g` (assuming node is installed).
Then ran it using `http-server "C:\directory_of_my_html_file" -a 127.0.0.1` and was then able to successfully access `window.ethereum` (browsing to http://localhost:8080/index.html).

Comment: Thanks.Thats true,i solve it befor 2 weeks,but thanks

Answer (score 0):

An easier way that worked for me is to install Live server extension for VSCode (VsCode users only)